# Прокрутка к последнему добавленному элементу в CollectionView

Tags: c#, maui

Почему может не работать `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"` у `CollectionView` ?

`Binding` на `ObservableCollection`

Элементы добавляются, поведение не меняется.

Ожидаю что при добавлении элементов видимость будет переходить на последний добавленный элемент, но этого не происходит и приходится скролить самому.

```
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                    ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                               ItemSpacing="10" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        ...
    </CollectionView>
```

Comment: [Баг?](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4116)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - да, он, спасибо) Я бы ещё долго пытался понять что не так...